# REPL asks for my clipboard when running discord.py code

Tags: python, discord.py

Whenever I try to run my script in which discord is imported, my REPL or any other interpreter asks me what I want on my clipboard.

This is my code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
import asyncio

Client = discord.Client()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="cazo.")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
        print(bot.user.name + " er klar til at bolle jer allesammen!")

@bot.command()
async def hello():
        await bot.say("Goddag, fede mongol.")

@bot.command(pass_context = True)
async def cazo(ctx):
        await bot.say("Cazo er jo den mægtigste person der findes.")



bot.run("TOKEN")
```

When I run it, the REPL shows

```
What do you want on your clipboard?
```

However, whenever I press enter, then it continues and the bot works fine. How can I make it stop?

Comment: How are you running your bot?  I don't see anything in your code that would cause that.

Comment: I just run it normally, like with every other code I run. But it only appears when discord is imported. If I # the import or just simply delete it, it doesn't appear but rahter gives an error and saying that much of the code is not defined, which makes sense, of course, 'cause discord isn't imported.

Comment: If you open an interactive session and just `import discord`, do you see the prompt then?

Comment: I am not entirely sure what an interactive session means. Sorry, I'm a little new.

Comment: The REPL you get when you run `python -i`

Comment: If I just write 'import discord', and press enter, it just moves on to the next line.